# What's an adjective for someone who doesn't feel sorry for themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests

To elaborate:
Someone who isn't easily affected by their own emotional distress
Someone who's tough and doesn't make their own problems into everyone else's problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome. For single-word requests, please give a sample sentence showing how you envision the word being used. That is espescially important for this question becaue the title asks specifically for a verb but the text seems to describe an adjective (eta: looked again, a noun)

Comment: Welcome Sue. I think you are looking for a noun, instead of a verb.

Comment: nope. i actually meant adjective, but thanks for pointing out my mistake c:

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear whether you want a verb or a noun, perhaps the latter.

A **stoic** is given by the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stoic) as

> NOUN — A person who can endure pain or hardship without showing their feelings or complaining.

With an example

> *If you are on one end of the bell curve and need minimal drugs to treat your pain, you're a stoic, a good chap.*

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stoic) has the slightly different

> adjective — determined not to complain or show your feelings, especially when something bad happens to you.

With an example

> *We knew she must be in pain, despite her stoic attitude.*

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're looking for an **adjective**. Depending on context, you might use **"stoical"**, **"phlegmatic"** or **"impassive"**.  A stoical kind of person tends to endure pain or hardship better than others. Phlegmatic implies an unemotional and calm response to external stimuli. Impassive is more related to facial expression.

> - **stoical** - "seemingly indifferent to or unaffected by pleasure or pain; impassive": "stoic resignation in the face of hunger" [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stoical) , showing austere indifference to joy, grief, pleasure, or pain; calm and unflinching under suffering, bad fortune, etc. [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stoical)
> - **phlegmatic** - "having or showing a slow and stolid temperament" [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phlegmatic) , "someone who is phlegmatic stays calm even when upsetting or exciting things happen" [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/phlegmatic) e.g. He was a most phlegmatic man, steadily working on as the rain splashed down.
> - **impassive** - "If someone is impassive or their face is impassive, they are not showing any emotion" e.g. "He searched Hill's impassive face for some indication that he understood.", "The lawyer looked impassively at him and said nothing." [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/impassive)